# How to select lines by line number?

Tags: functions

Need a function to select lines visually between the given start and end line number.

```
function! Select_Lines (start_line_number, end_line_number)
   ...
endfunction
```

Comment: Can you explain "select lines"? Visually (as in visual-mode)? Or for some other operation (_e.g._, see `:help [range]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you do it interactively:

1. go to line 4 with `:4`
2. press `V`
3. go to line 8 with `:8`

And then put it into your function:

```
" Visually select given lines
" from start (including) till the end (including)
" No errors are handled.
func! SelectLines(start, end) abort
    execute a:start
    normal! V
    execute a:end
endfunc
```

Where `execute` command executes given line number and puts cursor on that line. Command `normal!` executes original normal command `V` (visually select a line).

[image]

Comment: Would setting the `<`/`>` and `:normal! gv` also work?